# Customize SQL recordset order by specific value (s) if mentioned

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have an online store webapp which I wrote in classic ASP and SQL and I need help with the items order results.

I have table named "items" which looks like this:

```
ITEM_NUMBER | DESCRIPTION | PRICE | NEXT_ITEM |
-----------------------------------------------
0001          Item 0001       1.5
-----------------------------------------------
0002          Item 0002       2
-----------------------------------------------
0003          Item 0003       1
-----------------------------------------------
0004          Item 0004       3
-----------------------------------------------
0005          Item 0005       7        0030
-----------------------------------------------
.
.
.
.
-----------------------------------------------
0030          Item 0030       3
```

What I want to do is to keep the order by ITEM_NUMBER as it is by item no as the NEXT_ITEM value is null, but after item 0005 to show item 0030 as it's very similar item and the item number is mentioned in the row of item 0005.
After that need to return back the recordset pointer to continue load the results from the place it's skip (item 0006).

Once the recordset will get to 0030 I want it to skip this record as it's already visible to the user and already loaded before.

Comment: How deep can the NEXT_ITEM chain go?  Can you specify how you want the output to look?  Skipping the ones already displayed could be a simple `where ITEM_NUMBER not in (select NEXT_ITEM from Items)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to do the job - you need to join the table back to itself, and use that self-join in preference to the usual sort key:

```
declare @T table (ItemNo char(4) not null,Description varchar(20) not null,RelatedItemNo char(4) null)
insert into @T (ItemNo,Description,RelatedItemNo) values
('0001','0001',null),
('0002','0002',null),
('0003','0003',null),
('0004','0004',null),
('0005','0005','0009'),
('0006','0006',null),
('0007','0007',null),
('0008','0008',null),
('0009','0009',null),
('0010','0010',null)

select
    t.*
from
    @T t
        left join
    @T t_par
        on
            t.ItemNo = t_par.RelatedItemNo
order by
    COALESCE(t_par.ItemNo,t.ItemNo),
    t_par.RelatedItemNo
```

Result:

```
ItemNo Description          RelatedItemNo
------ -------------------- -------------
0001   0001                 NULL
0002   0002                 NULL
0003   0003                 NULL
0004   0004                 NULL
0005   0005                 0009
0009   0009                 NULL
0006   0006                 NULL
0007   0007                 NULL
0008   0008                 NULL
0010   0010                 NULL
```

---

This doesn't deal well with the situation where an item appears as a `RelatedItemNo` for multiple other rows - it would appear in each such location. But, there again, you didn't mention this possibility in your question, nor a specific rule for dealing with it, so I won't add any fix for this.

Also, if we need to extend this to multiple levels, the above is still inadequate - fixable by introducing a CTE. But, again, you haven't mentioned such a situation in your question.

Comment: @Ofirk - as I mention at the bottom of my answer, there are some limitations - Paul Williams was bringing up similar issues. We can do a lot more if we have realistic sample data and expected results. There's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) site where you can set up the data, if needed.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you so much for your answer, this is what I was looking for!
Sorry, actually the **RelatedItemNo** col is in another table named **PARAMETERS** and not in the same table **ITEMS**.
In my SQL statement I already did FULL JOIN for this table before because I have some parameters that I'm using there as conditions in the statement.
So for example I have:
SELECT DISTINCT ItemNo, Description.. FROM ITEMS FULL JOIN PARAMETERS ON ITEMS.ItemNo = PARAMETERS.ItemNo...
How can I LEFT JOIN the PARAMETERS and implement your code when the SELECT includes this table already? Thx

Comment: @Orfik - edit your question to include details (you can apply formatting there). and, again, try to include sample data and expected results. Mention any edge cases you're aware of.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever-thanks for your help, this is my demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abd9/1 You can see that not all rows returned because the item is out of stock or it's flagged as 'NO' under 'ShowItem'. I need help to implement your code in this SQL statement and to return the records in 'RelatedItemNo' order so the expected output will be: 0001,0002,0007,0004,0005,0009,0006,0008,0009. (I want to display 0007 after 0003 even if item 0003 not selected because a condition), this is the edge case, and the RelatedItemNo chain will go only per item and it will not loop. Many thanks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever-after I do LEFT JOIN again for PARAMETERS like the sample here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abd9/3 I get error **Ambiguous column name 'SHOWITEM'.:** because there is a conflict as same columns names after the LEFT JOIN. How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SQL Server you could add a `hierarchyid` column to your table and sort on that.

Alternately you could write a recursive CTE to order the results.